# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Engineering's [first moderator election](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: hazzey] [image: Wasabi]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

As you might recall, this is a [special *pro tempore* moderator election](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/announcing-a-pro-tempore-election), which means hazzey and Wasabi will need to run for re-election along with the rest of the moderators in the event this site graduates. This was also a non-competitive election because there were two candidates for two slots, so we skipped the voting stage.

Please join me in thanking Trevor Archibald and Air who are stepping down at this time.

Comment: I had seen Air's post about stepping down, and I was wondering about Trevor since I hadn't seen him around recently.  Good to know.