# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

[Engineering Stack Exchange's "graduation" election](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: NMech]

[image: Wasabi]

[image: hazzey]

NMech will be joining [the existing crew](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly. Wasabi and hazzey have already been serving as pro-tem moderators on the site [since being elected in 2018](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/575/34711). (Since this was the site's graduation election, any pro-tem mods who wished to continue serving as moderators needed to be reelected.) Please thank them all for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5114610075041792).